# Send email with default template Laravel

Tags: laravel, email

How I can send email with default template, have a `$data` params in body?
My code:

```
        Mail::send('vendor.mail.html.message', $data, function($message) use($data) {
            $message->to($data['email']);
            $message->subject('New notification');
        });
```

Default email template:

```
@component('mail::layout')
{{-- Header --}}
@slot('header')
    @component('mail::header', ['url' => config('app.url')])
        {{ config('app.name') }}
    @endcomponent
@endslot

{{-- Body --}}
{{ $slot }}

{{-- Subcopy --}}
@isset($subcopy)
    @slot('subcopy')
        @component('mail::subcopy')
            {{ $subcopy }}
        @endcomponent
    @endslot
@endisset

{{-- Footer --}}
@slot('footer')
    @component('mail::footer')
        &copy; {{ date('Y') }} {{ config('app.name') }}. All rights reserved.
    @endcomponent
@endslot
@endcomponent
```

I send `$data` params. How I can add this params on default email template without edit email template?

Comment: add your contents here replacing `{{-- Body --}}`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Define your variable like this

```
$data['slot']= "hello world";
$data['subcopy']= "Your Copy";
$data['email']= "email@email.com";
Mail::send('vendor.mail.html.message', $data, function($message) use($data) {
            $message->to($data['email']);
            $message->subject('New notification');
});
```